# Can I set disallow image in python selenium by using "chrome://settings/content/images"

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium for make some programs and I found that I don't need some images in specific pages. But, In some pages I need to load image...

Of course, I found the way that using
{"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
But, This sets browser not to load image in "All" pages...

So I was looking for disabling images in specific page, and I found there was a way to disallow in pages that i want to.
It is in (chrome://settings/content/images) and add some url (I'm korean so, I don't know how does it look like to you...)

So I was searching how to set chrome settings but there was no information that i need...

Maybe, it can be used by chrome_options in selenium.. but I can't find it on python selenium docs...

And I know that there is a way like this
driver.get("chrome://settings/content/images").find(cr-button id='addSite').click() ~~~~~~

But I want something clean so... I just want to set it when main code starts... so...

Anybody Can help me?

Comment: It's in a bunch of shadowroots(9)  first of so you have to do that first.

Comment: Then after that you can click it.

Comment: Oh But What I want is add urls not by using driver.find(By.Id,~~~~)...
but using like pref = "contentsImage = block: { www.example1, www.example2 }
There's no way to do like this?